# Python not printing in Mac terminal

Tags: python, macos, printing, terminal

I have some code that runs perfectly fine when I run it in the python module (Python 3.3). However, when I make it an executable and try to run it in my Mac terminal nothing prints out.

The beginning of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

marker = 1
prevchar = 'z'
prevstring = ""
#print("At place 1")

for line in sys.stdin:
    #print("At place 2")
    sys.stdout.write("% ")
    for c in line:
        #print("Starting loop")
```

In the terminal, when I take the comment sign off of "print("At place 1")", it prints. However, the same does not work for "print("At place 2")". What's wrong?

EDIT: I am putting data into stdin by just typing it into terminal. Maybe reading through a file would be better, though?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that there is no data on stdin? How are you running the program, are you piping data into it?

Comment: are you sure /usr/bin/python is not python 2.x ?

Comment: If you are typing stdin in the terminal, did you press ctrl+D to indicate EOF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you run? You need to pipe something in you case.

```
cat test | python sys_test_module.py
 At place 1
 At place 2
 At place 2
```

You might find this helpful http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Input_and_output